# Make Story Points required / mandatory when beginning a Sprint in Agile Jira(Greenhopper)

Tags: jira, agile, sprint, jira-agile

I want to require the Story Points field to be filled in, but only before starting all sprints.  Our team doesn't evaluate the size when first creating issues so it shouldn't be required that early.

Story points will be optional at start, we'd just want it mandatory before the sprint is started.

Does anything on the Issue-level change when the Sprint starts that an issue is in?

Would this be a configuration change in Jira Agile (formerly Greenhopper) or would this exist elsewhere?

Does the Behaviours plug-in support this functionality?

Comment: Is "Story Points" field currently a "required" field? So are you not able to add a new story without entering its points?

Comment: Story points is optional right now, we'd just want it mandatory to be filled in before the sprint is started.  It would hold work up to have to fill in story points before planning meetings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All that needed to be done was to configure the Estimation Statistic, specifically for Time Tracking.

It needs to be switched from "Remaining Estimate and Time Spent" to "None"(which also means it defaults to your Estimation Statistic for Time Tracking, in my case "Story Points")

https://support.atlassian.com/jira-software-cloud/docs/configure-estimation-and-tracking/